# I have a camera that can hold a memory stick pro?

Tags: camera, memorystick

Is it compatible with Memory Stick Pro DUO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you buy an adapter, it should work fine... However, it may not work on all capacities.

For example, my camera takes Memory Stick Pro, but I can use an adapter and a DUO up to 8GB... Anything over, it just doesn't recognise.